# Why does my code not display all added squares when moving up or down?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to recreate the classic snake game using Python. Whenever I have a train of 3 or more blocks, they display properly when moving either left or right but only two (the first one/head of the snake and the most recently added block) when it is moving up or down.
This section of code adds the new blocks to an empty list(snake_body):

```
        new_body = trtl.Turtle()
        new_body.penup()
        new_body.shape("square")
        new_body.color(rand.choice(colors))
        new_body.shapesize(1.8)
        snake_body.append(new_body)
```

And this section is what moves the entire snake:

```
  for index in range(len(snake_body)):
    x = snake_body[index - 1].xcor()
    y = snake.ycor()
    if (snake.heading() == 0):
      snake_body[index].goto(x - offset, y)
    elif (snake.heading() == 180):
      snake_body[index].goto(x + offset, y)
    elif (snake.heading() == 90):
      snake_body[index].goto(x - x_offset, y - y_offset)
      for index in range(len(snake_body) - 1):
        snake_body[index].goto(x + x_offset, y + y_offset)
        y_offset += 15
        x_offset += 5
    elif (snake.heading() == 270):
      snake_body[index].goto(x + x_offset, y + y_offset)
      for index in range(len(snake_body) - 1):
        snake_body[index].goto(x + x_offset, y + y_offset)
        y_offset -= 15
        x_offset += 5
    snake_body[index].speed(0)
    x_offset += 5
    y_offset = y_offset*index
```

I tried to use a for loop so that it would adjust all blocks in the snake, but that did not affect anything. I have tried it without the for loop nested in the elif statements and changing the y_offset variable significantly each time, but that also changed nothing. I am unsure why all of the blocks except for the first and last ones disappear while they are moving vertically.

Comment: What is `snake`?

Comment: snake is the first block/head of the snake

Comment: When the snake moves, the head moves in the current direction. All the other segments move to the old position of the previous segment, they don't care about the direction.

Comment: I added the if loops to detect the direction so that the blocks would offset left or right correctly, but are you saying that those are unnecessary? I removed them, and now the blocks appear but are slightly off to the side more and more as more blocks are added to the snake and this occurs as it is moving in any direction.